# Can I use Laravel's "Service Container pattern" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, polymorphism, repository-pattern

So, let's say that I am building a single-page app in JavaScript. For now I do not have a persistence layer in my app but I still need to write the code.

```
class App {
  handleClick(event) {
    User.saveToFile(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return 'Some template...';
  }
}
```

So, I create my concrete user class. But for now just save it to the local storage.

```
class User {
  constructor(localStorageHelper) {
    this.localStorageHelper = localStorageHelper;
  }

  save(name) {
    this.localStorageHelper.users.save({
      name
    });
  }
}
```

When the database is ready, I need to switch to the database. If I was in an object-oriented language I can simply create an interface and use polymorphism or repository pattern to solve this problem.

I was wondering what if I create an app container to contain all of the concrete implementations. For example I can create a `bindings.js` file like the following:

```
import UserPersister from './Repos/Db/User'
import PostPersister from './Repos/File/Post'

const Bindings = {

  'UserPersister': UserPersister,

  'PostPersister': PostPersister

};
```

So now in my App.js file. I can do something like:

```
let User = Container.make('UserPersister');

class App {
  handleClick(event) {
    User.saveToFile(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return 'Some template...';
  }
}
```

Now I can easily switch between different implementations by just changing them in bindings.js. If you've worked a little bit with Laravel this should seem familiar (except for the service providers of course).

This sounds OK to me but I am not sure if it is ACTUALLY OK to do this sort of thing in JavaScript. What advice would you give based on your experience with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reproduce laravel's pattern - that can be hard - but I can suggest you two technologies that can helps you with it. When you combained them you can easily implement quite similar code conception.

#### 1 [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

In fact you're using  it in above code. It's a kind of JavaScript wrapper in which you can write a code similar to `Java` solutions. You have access here to `polymorphism`, `inheritance` and `encapsulation` like in typical PHP OOP. This can speed up your work a bit and it's pure and it's uses [ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/).

#### 2 AngularJS

The large JS Framework which is very strong and have big community. This one privides you for example injection service (like Laravel's IoC) which will automaticcly resolve all your dependencies. You can create easily repositories using `$resources` which is ajax wrapper for REST API requests. There are service providers that works greate on application load. And the best is that - yo can build one-page-application with Angular. It have many other advanteges. There is stable [version 1](https://angularjs.org/) and [unstable verison 2](https://angular.io/) which is developed in `TypeScript`.

With these two tools you can build awesome stuff for the frontend (client side). If you want more tools here it is:

- [PuppetJS](https://github.com/PuppetJs/puppet-js) - server side generating client side JS scripts (one implementation fort both sides!).
- [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) - great library based on components

Comment: Thanks but this really doesn't answer my question. I was asking it ia OK to write something like this in JS cuz we do not usually see this kind of stuff in JS. Anyways I already use React and ECMAScript2015